# Проблема работы с временем в kotlin

Tags: android, дата, datetime

В моем приложении есть чат , и в чате при отправке сообщения в бд в документе сообщения есть поле date которое формируется при отправке через Date() , когда я получаю все сообщения я их сортирую как раз по этому полю , но если на одном устройстве допустим время 18:01 , а на втором 18:02 (то есть у второго спешат на минуту ) , то в date запишется время 18:02 а не 18:01 , из-за этого  некорректный порядок сообщений на экране , порылся в документации не нашел решения своей проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Для решения этой проблемы необходимо записывать серверное время, а не время с компьютера. Для это в разных базах данных используют разные переменные или функции. Например

> MSSQL - GETDATE()

> MongoDB - $currentDate

После этого проблема с порядком сообщений будет исправлена

Comment: спасибо большое , вы мне очень помогли